# Access the message from Html.Kendo().Upload()

Tags: kendo-asp.net-mvc

C# return from ActionResult method;

a success is indicated by an empty string:

```
return("");
```

a fail can be any text in the string:

```
return Content($"Maximum number (which is: {model.max}) reached.");
```

I noticed that in the Console of the browser, I get:

> Server response: Maximum number (which is: 5) reached.

Is there a way of accessing that text from the Event onError()?

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone else gets to this: e.XMLHttpRequest.responseText is what worked for me.
this link, was useful: https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/upload/events/error

```
function onError(e) {
    $('#uploadErrorMessage').text(e.XMLHttpRequest.responseText);
}
```